# How do i create a 3d surface plot in R If I have a dataframe of 3 columns?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Here are the first 20 rows of my dataframe:

```
            x             y        z
1        0.50          0.50 48530.98
2        0.50          0.51 49029.34
3        0.50          0.52 49576.12
4        0.50          0.53 50161.22
5        0.50          0.54 50752.05
6        0.50          0.55 51354.43
7        0.50          0.56 51965.09
8        0.50          0.57 38756.51
9        0.50          0.58 39262.34
10       0.50          0.59 39783.68
11       0.51          0.60 41052.09
12       0.51          0.61 41447.51
13       0.51          0.62 26972.85
14       0.51          0.63 27134.74
15       0.51          0.64 27297.85
16       0.51          0.65 27462.82
17       0.51          0.66 27632.45
18       0.51          0.67 27806.77
19       0.51          0.68 27988.12
20       0.51          0.69 25514.42
```

I need to create a 3d surface plot to view it. 
The best would be one where I can rotate it around angles to view it from all perspectives.

Thanks.

Comment: The first hit of a Google search for "3d surface plot in R" is [3D Surface Plots in R](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/); seems to tick all your boxes (3D surface plot, rotate-able). It comes with sample R code too.

Comment: But I got confused on how to turn that dataframe into the necessary input.

Comment: There are many ways to convert the data, one option is to use `xtabs`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `plotly` to create a 3d surface plot. Use `xtabs` to turn your data into a suitable `matrix`

```r
library(plotly)
plot_ly(z = ~xtabs(z ~ x + y, data = df)) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "           x             y        z
1        0.50          0.50 48530.98
2        0.50          0.51 49029.34
3        0.50          0.52 49576.12
4        0.50          0.53 50161.22
5        0.50          0.54 50752.05
6        0.50          0.55 51354.43
7        0.50          0.56 51965.09
8        0.50          0.57 38756.51
9        0.50          0.58 39262.34
10       0.50          0.59 39783.68
11       0.51          0.60 41052.09
12       0.51          0.61 41447.51
13       0.51          0.62 26972.85
14       0.51          0.63 27134.74
15       0.51          0.64 27297.85
16       0.51          0.65 27462.82
17       0.51          0.66 27632.45
18       0.51          0.67 27806.77
19       0.51          0.68 27988.12
20       0.51          0.69 25514.42", header = T)
```