# error using plotly " more elements in the method signature (2) than in the generic signature (1) for function ‘asJSON’"

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

My error here is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097256/more-elements-in-the-method-signature-2-than-in-the-generic-signature-1-for), but I couldn't understand how to use the solution for that post for my situation.- I am using xtabs to convert data in columns to a matrix for a plotly surface plot [as per this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369552/how-do-i-create-a-3d-surface-plot-in-r-if-i-have-a-dataframe-of-3-columns). In the real df, there is more than one value in the second column (the dataset was created using expand.grid to get some model predictions).

An example:

```
df <- read.table(text =
  "WtavR  WcsavR      pred
1  18.62672 0.03825 0.6113332
2  18.73131 0.03825 0.6079856
3  18.83590 0.03825 0.6046379
4  18.94049 0.03825 0.6012903
5  19.04508 0.03825 0.5979427
6  19.14967 0.03825 0.5945950
7  19.25426 0.03825 0.5912474
8  19.35885 0.03825 0.5878998
9  19.46344 0.03825 0.5845521
10 19.56803 0.03825 0.5812045
11 19.67262 0.03825 0.5778568
12 19.77721 0.03825 0.5745092
13 19.88180 0.03825 0.5711616
14 19.98639 0.03825 0.5678139
15 20.09098 0.03825 0.5644663
16 20.19557 0.03825 0.5611187
17 20.30016 0.03825 0.5577710
18 20.40475 0.03825 0.5544234
19 20.50934 0.03825 0.5510758
20 20.61393 0.03825 0.5477281", header = T)


p6 <- plot_ly(z = ~xtabs(pred ~ WtavR + WcsavR, data = df)) %>% add_surface()

p6
```

This gives the following error

> Error in matchSignature(signature, fdef) :
> more elements in the method signature (2) than in the generic signature (1) for function ‘asJSON’

I would appreciate any help. I am just after a surface plot of model predictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xtabs()` produces an object of class `xtabs` rather than a plain matrix.
By removing that class, I found that I could get `plotly` to behave:

```
df      <- expand.grid(x=0:9, y=0:9) %>% mutate(z=x*y)
surface <- unclass(xtabs(z ~ x + y, data = df))
plot_ly(z = ~surface) %>% add_surface()
```

[image: plotly surface]

Comment: Thanks for that David :)